# How to wrap text around images on Google Docs API?

Tags: gdata-api, gdata, google-docs

I am uploading html document to Google Docs thru API. All images are set inline, but I prefer fixed (text wraps around). Is there a way to mark it on html, so that imported document has each image correct way aligned or is there a way to set image wrapping on API before uploading?

For a reference this is what I want, but doing it automatically:

https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-using-images-in-google.html

Comment: Sorry, I would ask you something that it doesn't concern with the question: does your html doc contain public images or do you succeed in embedding them in the html in some way (or do you upload them on GDocs and then link them in the doc)?

Comment: They have public images by regular img tags when I upload html pages to the docs.

Comment: I thought you worked with local imgs. I've tried to use base64 encoding without success. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I think something like this

```
<body style="background-image: url('test3.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-attachment: scroll;"> color name <br><br><br></body>

<body style="background-image: url('test3.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-attachment: fixed;"> color name <br><br><br></body>
```

see **background-attachment: fixed**